# What are the coins Ogres drop used for?

Tags: orcs-must-die

When killing an Ogre they drop this large coin.

What does picking this up do? I haven't been able to see any benefits to picking it up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It gives you money the same way killing an orc does except that you must go to pick it up and isn't given to you automatically after killing one.

Comment: Upgrading is via skulls, buying is via coins